# What is the difference between downloading the AngularJS Script for an HTML file and just referenceing the script off of ajax.googleapis.com?

Tags: angularjs

In certain tutorials and applications (e.i. codeschool) I see that the HTML file includes AngularJS with a simple script tag reference to "angular.min.js", whereas in others (e.i. w3schools), the script tag references "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js".  Is the latter just to get around having to download AngularJS? If you were going to deploy a website using AngularJS, is there a correct way to refer to the angular script (download or no download)?

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com/why-use-a-cdn.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing to e.g. `/assets/js/angular.min.js` means loading Angular from your disk because you saved this location somewhere in your project. When you reference it from a CDN or some other hosting, it is downloaded from this resource, once the .html page is called.

Yes, the CDN version gets you around downloading and storing it yourself.
There is no correct way how to refer to Angular as a library but there are quite some.

However, most popular for productive applications is having a build script, that knows how to look for your scripts on your disk, concatenate them, minify them and reference them in one local file. This ensures downloading only one file that is as small as possible to save performance.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax below is used to attach `JS` Externally

```
<script src=""></script>
```

if `src="abc.js"` it means it is on the same server as html file

if `src="http://example.com/abc.js"` it means it is loaded from CDN